# calculate distance in km using gps

Tags: android, gps

I wrote following java file for display distance with the help of  gps in android .it shows distance in toast but i want to show it in km so how can i do it ?

```
    package com.dansaurabh.speedone;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.GpsStatus.Listener;
    import android.location.Criteria;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class gpslocation extends Service {
    public final static String key1 = "com.saurabh.speedone.mes1";
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location currentLoc;
    // Double par1,par2,par3,par4;
    private double par1 = 0;
    private double par2 = 0;
    private double currentlong = 0;
    private double currentlat = 0;
    String distance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("LocationUpdateService", "onCreate is called");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        /* ################ */

        final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        /* ################ */
        Log.d("LocationUpdateService", "onStartCommand is called");

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == 
     false) {
            // put dialoug box of start gps service
            // getNetworkLocation();
            // add dilouge for start gps

            Toast.makeText(this, "start GPS service", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            getGPSLocation();
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    /*
     * private void getNetworkLocation(){ Log.d("LocationUpdateService",
     * "getNetworkLocation is called"); currentLoc =
     * locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
     * 
     * String data = "Network : " + currentLoc.getLatitude() + " :: "
     * +currentLoc.getLongitude(); // updateUI(data); } // above tells about
     * last known location
     */

    private void getGPSLocation() {

        /*
         * Log.d("LocationUpdateService", "getGPSLocation is called");
         * currentLoc =
         * locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         * if(currentLoc!=null){ String data = "getLastKnownLocation : GPS : " +
         * currentLoc.getLatitude() + " :: " +currentLoc.getLongitude(); //
         * updateUI(data);
         * 
         * 
         * }else{ updateUI("No GPS Current Loc found"); }
         */
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, new LocationListener() {

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int 
    status,
                            Bundle extras) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // updateUI(provider + " Enabled");
                    }

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // updateUI(provider + " Disabled");
                    }

                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        currentLoc = locationManager

   .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (currentLoc != null) {

                            currentlat = 
    currentLoc.getLatitude();
                            currentlong = 
    currentLoc.getLongitude();
                            distance();
                            // in km

                        }
    else {
    Toast.makeText(gpslocation.this, "no location changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
                    }

                    public void distance() {
                        // measure distance

                        double earthRadius = 3958.75;

                        double dLat = Math.toRadians(par1 -  
    currentlat);
                        double dLng = Math.toRadians(par2 - 
    currentlong);
                        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * 
    Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                                + 
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(currentlat))
                                * 
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(par1))
                                * Math.sin(dLng / 2) *  
    Math.sin(dLng / 2);
                        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),
                                Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                        double dist = earthRadius * c;


                        Intent it = new Intent(gpslocation.this, 
    Run.class);
                        it.putExtra(key1, distance);

                        startActivity(it);
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // updateUI("onDestroy is called");
        Toast.makeText(this, "app closeing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent it = new Intent(gpslocation.this, Run.class);
        it.putExtra(key1, distance);

        startActivity(it);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void updateUI(CharSequence dist) {
        Log.i("LocationUpdateService,distance", "Data :: " + dist);
        Toast.makeText(this, dist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    }
```

plz help me thanks in advance

Comment: Isnt the distance already displayed as kilometres ? Or are you asking how to show "1234 km" in the Toast ?

Comment: what is your question? how to convert meters to kilometers?

Comment: @AlexWien : In his code, the output will be shown as meters  ?

Comment: it shows like 1234.2564 this

Comment: it already is kilometers, where is your problem?

Comment: actually in tested this code on my phone and in give me 7894.264

Comment: And how would you like it to be ?

Comment: actually in tested this code on my phone and in give me 7894.264 something large amount event i walk only 0.5 km or less so i am getting confused

Comment: as show in digital meter 1,2 ,2.5 km like that

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then it's as simple as :

```
private void updateUI(CharSequence dist) {
    Log.i("LocationUpdateService,distance", "Data :: " + dist);
    Toast.makeText(this, dist.toString() + " km", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: In that case store the value in a global variable and use textView.setText("distanceValue");

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide meaningful variable names. What is `par1` and `par2`? I bet not even you will know at first glance some time from now. It *looks like* you're using this to calculate the distance (defining both to 0 and not setting again), **therefore you are calculating the distance to the North Pole** (sorry, not losing too much time analyzing a code that should be made simpler).
2. In Android, prefer using the `Location` object if you can, instead of raw, `double` coordinates.
3. Calculation for long distances (and even smallish ones) is a tricky thing. Don't pretend you can do it better than others before you. As AlexWien said in the answer before me, seach for an appropriate formula. Or, *better yet*, use the built-in [Location.distanceTo(Location)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29), which returns the distance to another point, in **meters**. For customization (? - not sure how extendable the Android API is in that regard, I'd bet it is fully), there are [libraries](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula-java/) on the net that you can use as well.

If this was me, I'd provide my built-in, referenced `Location` (say, `Location myDestination`), retrieve the current `Location` (say, `Location currentLocation`), and use `currentLocation.distanceTo(myDestination)`. Then, I'd probably transform and round this value to provide a nice output in kilometers (or miles, for you anglo-saxons), using the well known ways in Java to round numbers for nice output.

*Much* simpler, if you ask me. :)